# Matrix multiplication from files in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, multidimensional-array

Hello i have go a assignment where i have 3 files a,b and c which contains 2 matrix which i have to multiply. In all a and b the first line is the size of the array and the next line is the contetnt for that array. c is the output of multiplication of the matrix. When i run the program i get a segmentation fault, and i cant seem to find the problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int **arrayA; //unallocated array A
int **arrayB; //unallocated array B
int **arrayC; //unallocated array C
int rA, cA; //Size of A
int rB, cB; //Size of B
int rC, cC; //Size of C

/*int matrixmultiplication(int *arrayA, int *arrayB, int *arrayC)//Function that multiplice the matrix
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rC; i = i + 1)
        for (int j = 0; j < cC; j = j + 1)
        {
            arrayC[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < cA; k = k + 1)
                arrayC[i][j] = arrayC[i][j] + arrayA[i][k] * arrayB[k][j];
        }

}*/

int main(void)// Main function
{
    //File pointer to A, B and C
    FILE *Aptr;
    FILE *Bptr;
    FILE *Cptr;
    //Opening the files containing the information for the matrix
    Aptr = fopen("/home/au/Desktop/Matrixmulti/a", "r");
    if(Aptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!! opening file A");
        exit(1);
    }

    Bptr = fopen("/home/au/Desktop/Matrixmulti/b", "r");
    if(Bptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!! opening file B");
        exit(1);
    }

    Cptr = fopen("/home/au/Desktop/Matrixmulti/c", "w");
    if(Cptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!! opening file C");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Scan file a for size of matrix a and matrix b
    fscanf(Aptr, "%d", &rA);
    fscanf(Aptr, "%d", &cA);
    fscanf(Bptr, "%d", &rB);
    fscanf(Bptr, "%d", &cB);
    rC = rA;
    cC = cB;
    //Allocating space for the arrays
    arrayA = malloc(rA * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++)
        {
            arrayA[i] = malloc(cA * sizeof(int));
        }
    arrayB = malloc(rB * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < rB; i++)
        {
            arrayB[i] = malloc(cB * sizeof(int));
        }
    arrayC = malloc(rC * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < rC; i++)
        {
            arrayA[i] = malloc(cC * sizeof(int));
        }

    //Scan file a for data for matrix a
    for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cA; j++)
        {
            fscanf(Aptr, "%d", &arrayA[i][j]);
        }
        
    }
    

    //Scan file b for data for matrix b
    for (int i = 0; i < rB; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++)
        {
            fscanf(Bptr, "%d", &arrayB[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //Matrix multiplication
    for (int i = 0; i < rC; i = i + 1)
        for (int j = 0; j < cC; j = j + 1)
        {
            arrayC[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < cA; k = k + 1)
                arrayC[i][j] = arrayC[i][j] + arrayA[i][k] * arrayB[k][j];
        }
        
    //Print result matrix to file c
    for (int i = 0; i < rC; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cC; j++)
        {
            fprintf(Cptr, "%d \t", arrayC[i][j]);
        }
        
    }
    



    //Closing the files
    fclose(Aptr);
    fclose(Bptr);
    fclose(Cptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your program under a debugger and you'll be quickly greeted with a concrete reason where things went south.

Comment: Typo: `arrayA[i] = malloc(cC * sizeof(int));` Should be `arrayC`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you so much i have been looking at it for 3 hours and it was a simple typo